# Duvida de modularização de classes

Tags: java, swing, mvc, modularização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para fins didáticos, trabalho da faculdade de final de semestre, neste irá fazer CRUD das disciplinas em uma tabela no banco já criada, **"DISCIPLINES"**, pensei em criar uma lista de processos, caso o usuário deseje refazer suas alterações, tipo crt+z, é após fazer as alterações e estar certo disto, executar as alterações. deste modo:

O usuário faz uma operação de crud pela interface gráfica, e após as alterações, ao clicar em OK, executa a lista de processos.
segue o código dos métodos que gera, deleta e executa os processos:

```
//Implentação da interface omitidos
@Override
    public void setupEvents() {
        //evento do botão deletar disciplina
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rowIndex = tbListDisciplines.getSelectedRow();
                int id = (int)tbListDisciplines.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
                InvokerRemove delete = new InvokerRemove(id, new ControllerDiscipline());
                queue.addProcess(delete);
                lblAmountDisciplines.setText("" + tbListDisciplines.getRowCount());
                model.remove(rowIndex);
            }
        });

        //evento do botão alterar disciplina
        btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rowIndex = tbListDisciplines.getSelectedRow();
                int id = (int)tbListDisciplines.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
                String name = tfNameDiscipline.getText();
                InvokerUpdateRefatorar update = new InvokerUpdateRefatorar(id, name, new ControllerDiscipline());
                queue.addProcess(update);
                System.out.println(name);

                Discipline marca = new Discipline();
                marca.setName(tfNameDiscipline.getText());
                model.update(rowIndex, marca);  
            }
        });

        //evento que finaliza as alterações e executa os processos de crud.
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                glassPanel.start();
                queue.executeProcess();
                model.clearlistRemoved();
                Thread performer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        perform();
                    }
                }, "Performer");
                performer.start();
            }
        }); 

        //evento do botão cancelar, e invoca o método sair.
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                quit();

            }
        });

        //MouseListener para preencher o textField
        tbListDisciplines.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int rowIndex = tbListDisciplines.getSelectedRow();
                tfNameDiscipline.setText((String)tbListDisciplines.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 1));
            }
        });
    }
    //outros métodos omitidos
```

Caso o usuário deseja desfazer a alteração, ele clica em cancelar (eu ainda estou implementado uma forma melhor de fazer isso, por exemplo, crt+z para desfazer a ultima alteração) código a baixo:

```
@Override
    public void quit() {
        if(!model.isEmptyList()){
             int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Deseja sair, as alterações feita não serão salvas ?",
                        "Desistir das alterações?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             if(confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                 this.dispose();
                 model.clearlistRemoved();
             }
        } else{
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
```

apenas por uma questão de beleza adicionei um glassPane para simular um processo coisa bem simples.

Na questão de gerar a lista de processos eu estou utilizando o Pattern Command, crie uma queue de processos, *QueuesProcess*, que será responsável por receber todas as "operações de crud" segue o código:

```
/**
 * Classe responsável por criar uma fila de processos, CRUD, 
 * remove processos da fila para casos de refazer as decisões anteriores
 * e limpa a fila para os próximos processos.
 * <br><br>
 * Nome do projeto: MeOrganize  <br>
 * Integra ao pocote: utfpr.tsi.meOrganize.controller.impl<br>
 * @author Vinicius Cavalcanti
 * @since implementação da aplicação
 * @version 1.0v 2016
 */
public class QueuesProcess {
    private Queue<IECommand> process;

    /**
     * construtor inicializa a lista de processos
     */
    public QueuesProcess() {
        process = new LinkedList();
    }

    /**
     * Método que adiciona processos a lista
     * @param process - o processo que será adicionado a fila
     */
    public void addProcess(IECommand process) {
        this.process.add(process);
    }

    /**
     * Método que remove um processo adicionado
     * @param process - processo que será removido
     */
    public void removeProcess(IECommand process) {
        this.process.remove(process);
    }

    /**
     * Método que limpa a lista para casos
     * de sair da janela e cancelar as operações (CRUD) 
     */
    public void clearQueues() {
        this.process.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Método que executa as operações na fila e limpa a fila.
     */
    public void executeProcess() {
        for(IECommand command : this.process)
            command.execute();

        process.clear();
    }
}
```

Bem como havia dito estou usando o pattern command, sendo assim criei uma interface IEcommand para o contrato dos invoker com apenas o comando executar. Seque os código abaixo:

```
/**
 * Contrato da fila de comandos CRUD.
 * <br><br>
 * Nome do projeto: MeOrganize  <br>
 * Integra ao pocote: utfpr.tsi.meOrganize.controller<br>
 * @author Vinicius Cavalcanti
 * @since
 * @version  2016
 */
public interface IECommand {

    void execute();

}
```

E uma classe abstrata para os pedidos de crud, vou criar um controller para cada tabela, neste caso estou mostrando apenas das disciplinas, mas, terá outras entidades, como por exemplo, a agenda de estudo, o planejamento.

```
/**
 * Classe abstrata responsável pelos pedidos de Crud 
 * para camada dao, antes de inserir faz uma busca no banco
 * para verificar se a entidade já existe e retonar o resultado.
 * <br><br>
 * Nome do projeto: MeOrganize  <br>
 * Integra ao pocote: utfpr.tsi.meOrganize.controller.impl<br>
 * @author Vinicius Cavalcanti
 * @since implentação da aplicação
 * @version 1.0c 2016
 * @param <T> entidade 
 * @param <E> qual dao será utilizado.
 */
public abstract class Controller<T, E> implements IERegister<T, E>{

    protected IEDAO dao;
    protected IEEntity entity;

    public Controller(IEDAO dao, IEEntity entity) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    /**
     * Método responsável por pedir a camada dao a inserção 
     * na tabela da entidade.
     * @return - retorna true se a inserção foi feita, false se não é o erro.
     * @throws - erro se a entidade veio nula.
     */
    public boolean add(String name) throws EntityNull {
        this.entity.setName(name);

        if(exists() == false) {
            try {
                dao.insert(entity);
            } catch (EntityNull | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Não foi possivel adicionar ao banco porque:\n" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Método responsável por pedir a remoção da entidade da tabela.
     * A remoção e feita por uma busca pelo id da entidade.
     * @return - retorna true se a remoção foi feita, false se não é o erro.
     * @throws - erro se a entidade veio nula.
     */
    public boolean remove(int id) throws EntityNull{
        try {
            this.dao.remove(id);
        } catch (EntityNull | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possível remover porque:\n" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Método responsável por pedir a camada dao a alteração na entidade.
     * faz uma busca pelo id da entidade e pede a alteração.
     * @throws - erro se a entidade veio nula.
     */
    public void update(int id, String name) throws EntityNull{
        this.entity.setId(id);
        this.entity.setName(name);

        try {
            this.dao.update(entity);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel atualizar a entidade no banco porque:\n" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Método que verifica se a entidade já existe na tabale.
     * faz uma busca na tabela pela entidade 
     * @return true se a entidade já existe, falso se não.
     */
    public boolean exists() {

        ArrayList<IEEntity<T>> entitys = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            entitys.addAll(dao.searchData());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel fazer a busca no banco porque:\n" + e.getMessage());
        }

        for(IEEntity enti : entitys) {
            if(entity.getName().equals(enti.getName())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entidade já existe", "Erro no cadastro da entidade", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}


/**
 * Contrato de controller das classe que recebe os dados
 * para envidar para a camada DAO para manipular os dados das entidadades
 * do banco de dados.
 * <br><br>
 * Nome do projeto: MeOrganize  <br>
 * Integra ao pocote: utfpr.tsi.meOrganize.controller<br>
 * @author Vinicius Cavalcanti
 * @since implementação da aplicação
 * @version 1.0v 2016
 * @param <T> Entidade que será passado para camada DAO.
 * @param <E> Dao que será utilizado para entidade.
 */
public interface IERegister<T, E> {

    /**
     * Método responsável para enviar a camada DAO a entidade para salvar
     * @param obj a entidade
     * @throws EntityNull exceção de entidade nula.
     */
    boolean add(String name) throws EntityNull;

    /**
     * Método responsável para enviar a camada DAO a entidade, por parâmetro o id,
     * que será deletado.
     * @param id - O id da entidade
     * @throws EntityNull exceção de entidade nula.
     */
    boolean remove(int id) throws EntityNull;

    /**
     * Método que verifica se a entidade já existe ou não
     * @param dao
     * @param entity
     * @return true para existe e false para não existe.
     */
     boolean existsDiscipline(T dao, E entity);

    /**
     * Método responsável para enviar a camada DAO a entidade, por parâmentro o id,
     * que será alterado.
     * @param id - O id da entidade.
     * @throws EntityNull exceção de entidade nula.
     */
     void update(int id, String name) throws EntityNull;

}
```

Outra classe que herda os métodos da classe abstrata para fazer o crud, neste caso das disciplinas.

```
/**
 * Classe concreta responsável por gerenciar os pedidos de crud
 * para camada dao.
 * <br><br>
 * Nome do projeto: MeOrganize  <br>
 * Integra ao pocote: utfpr.tsi.meOrganize.controller.impl<br>
 * @author Vinicius Cavalcanti
 * @since implementação da aplicação
 * @version 1.0v 2016
 */
public class ControllerDiscipline extends Controller{

    /**
     * construtor que manda para super classe um
     * entidade criada pelo dao.
     */
    public ControllerDiscipline() {
        super(new DisciplineDAO(), new DisciplineDAO().create());
    }

    /**
     * Método que faz a inserção.
     * @return true se inserção bem sucedida false se não.
     * @throws - exceção se a entidade está nula
     */
    public boolean add(String name) throws EntityNull{
        return super.add(name);
    }

    /**
     * Método que faz a remoção.
     * @return true se remoção bem sucedida false se não.
     * @throws - exceção se a entidade está nula
     */
    public boolean remove(int id) throws EntityNull{
        return super.remove(id);
    }

    /**
     * Método que faz a alteração.
     * @return true se alteração bem sucedida false se não.
     * @throws - exceção se a entidade está nula
     */
    public void update(int id, String name) throws EntityNull {
        super.update(id, name);     
    }

    /**
     * Método que verifica se a entidade já existe.
     * @return true se sim. false se não.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean existsDiscipline(Object dao, Object entity) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Bem explicado o contexto. Agora é que vêm a minha dúvida se estou fazendo certo, pois nosso professor vai avaliar a elegância do código também, não basta estar funcionando, o trabalho "sistema" devera estar bem escrito, com uso moderado de patterns e uma estrutura boa.
Eu criei uma classe para cada crud (InvokerAdd, IinvokerRemove, InvokerUpdate) como vocês podem ver no código da interface, eu crio um remover, e instancio no fila.

```
btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rowIndex = tbListDisciplines.getSelectedRow();
                int id = (int)tbListDisciplines.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
                InvokerRemove delete = new InvokerRemove(id, new ControllerDiscipline());
                queue.addProcess(delete);
                lblAmountDisciplines.setText("" + tbListDisciplines.getRowCount());
                model.remove(rowIndex);
            }
        });
```

Que vai popular a fila de processos. com apenas um método. Vou postar apenas a de adicionar mas, serve para todas, unica alteração é os parâmetros, em pensei em fazer uma sobre carga de métodos trocando os parâmetros não, sempre que eu adicionar um novo "método" estou quebrando o  principio (OpenClose) do solid?

Vocês poderiam me aconselhar em uma melhor implementação?

Comment: Você parece estar violando o padrão MVC em alguns lugares. Por exemplo, a sua classe abstrata `Controller` usa o `JOptionPane` que é algo que deveria estar apenas na view. Além disso, criar os controllers dentro do `ActionListener` da view é outra violação, pois é o controller que deveria controlar a view, não o contrário.

Comment: Entendi obrigado pela dica, refatorado, fiz um if para retornar o erro. na view, quanto o actionListener, não é o controller que espera uma requisição da view? Meio que não entendi o que vc quis dizer como o controller controlar a view...

Comment: Quando você dá um `new ControllerDiscipline()` dentro do `ActionListener`, que faz parte da view, você está violando o MVC. Isso significa que a view está criando a controller, sendo que é a controller que deveria criar a view. Ou seja, você tem que injetar uma instância da controller dentro da sua `JFrame` (ou algo semelhante), e nunca fazer com que o seu `JFrame` (ou uma `ActionListener` dela) fique responsável por instanciar a view.

Comment: A ideia é que você crie o modelo, crie a controller, forneça o modelo ao controller e então o controller cria as views e liga ela ao modelo. Fazer o próprio controller criar o modelo pode ser aceitável também. O que não pode é a view criar o controller ou a view criar o modelo, ou o modelo conhecer o controller ou a view (o contrário pode), ou a view fazer operações que alterem o modelo sem ser por intermédio da controller.

Comment: Ah entendi, neste caso, poderia fazer uma classe com um método estático que retorna um objeto controller?

Comment: Enquanto coisa melhor não surgir, sim, pode.